# What is the power of an ideal in the commutative unital ring R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If I is an ideal in a commutative unital ring R, then what is the elements of $I^{n}$?

P.S. I know the definition JK, where J and K are different ideals. It's all the possible finite sum of their product, but if I use this definition, then $I^{n}=I$, so I think it's wrong. Could someone give me the right definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you say, for ideals $J,K\subset R$,  $JK$ is an ideal generated by set $$\{jk\in R\mid j\in J, k\in K\}$$ So $I^n$ is an ideal generated by set $$\left\{\prod_{i= 1}^n a_i\mid  a_i\in I\right\}$$ So not necessary $I^n=I$.

For example $I=k\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $I^n=k^n\mathbb{Z}\neq I.$ (if $k\neq 0,\pm1$)

Comment: Sorry I missed.

Comment: Sorry. 1. Does JK part need to add a sigma(finite sum)? 2. But the $I^{n}$ is correct, right?

Comment: @JudyJudy No, he says it's *generated by the set* not that it is *equal to the set*.  You could reexpress $I^n$ as the finite sums of generators, yes.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.